# How to add some text on the header of the time picker in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using showTimePicker two times in my code to display time picker back to back, so that user could select time twice. Once for the opening time and another for the closing time.

```
  TimeOfDay openTime = await showTimePicker(
   context: context,
   initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now()));

 if (openTime == null) {
   return;
 }

 TimeOfDay closeTime = await showTimePicker(
   context: context,
   initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now()));

 if (closeTime == null) {
   return;
 }
```

I want to add some text in the header part of the picker to distinguish between time pickers. For first one text should be "Select Opening Time" and for second one it should be "Select Closing Time" but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: do you need it on the time picker box or is it ok above it?

Comment: @LoVe I am completely fine to show it on the of the screen in separate card or just hightlighted text but it would be great if I could add it on the picker box as separate text/card might not go with the design.

Comment: Ok you can use the builder parameter which gives you the picker widget and context,you then wrap  the picker widget in a column with text and return it from the builder,I will not post an answer because it is not the best solution,or tell me if you didn't get it

Comment: I dint know that we can do this with builder, it worked like a charm in my case. I added a card above the picker widget wrapped in a column, thanks.

Comment: i will add an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The showTimePicker method has a builder parameter, you can use it to wrap the timer picker widget with any structure of your choice